# Use of $\lor$ and $\land$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, notation

I'm having some trouble understanding the notation in the following statement:

If $(\Omega, F)$ is a measure space with a measure $\mu$ and $f : \Omega\to R$ is $F$-measurable, then we can define $\int$fdµ (for non-negative $f$ , also if both $f \lor 0$ and $−f\land 0$ and have finite integrals)

What do the $\lor$ and $\land$ mean?

Comment: $\vee$ is max and $\wedge$ is min

Comment: To help you remember, $\lor$ is logic or, $\land$ is logic and. So it makes sense to define it like we do.

Comment: @jlammy so would f ∨ 0 mean that the max value of f is $0$?

Comment: $f \lor 0$ is the function $x \mapsto \max(f(x), 0)$. I.e., it's the "non-negative part" of $f$.

Comment: It might also be interpreted as saying: the set of functions $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a lattice under the product order, and we're using the meet and join operations from that lattice.  (Amounts to the same thing, but casts it as a special case of a general concept.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an “and” too many – it should be “if both $f\lor0$ and $f\land0$ have finite integrals”. $f\lor0=\max(f,0)$ and $f\land0=\min(f,0)$, so these are the positive and negative components of $f$, respectively.